# stringr vectorization fails when matching first element

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I'm encountering something strange when using `stringr` and searching for a `pattern` of length > 1. I want to eventually use `str_which` along with `purrr::map()` as:

```
searcher <- c("new1", "var1")
purrr::map(data, function(x), any(str_which(x, searcher)))
```

#### Sample data

```
library(stringr)
data <- dplyr::tibble(
                         a = 1:8,
                         b = rep(paste0("var", 1:2), each = 4),
                         c = rep(paste0("new", 1:4), 2))
str_which(data$c, c("new1", "var1"))
#[1] 1 5
str_which(data$c, c("var1", "new1"))
#integer(0)
str_which(data$b, c("var1", "new1"))
#[1] 1 3
str_which(data$b, c("new1", "var1"))
#[1] 2 4
str_which(data$a, c(2, "var1"))
#integer(0)
str_which(data$a, c(3, "var1"))
#[1] 3
```

Moreover, I am noticing strange behavior with `str_locate`:

```
str_locate(data$b, c("new1", "var1"))
#     start end
#[1,]    NA  NA
#[2,]     1   4
#[3,]    NA  NA
#[4,]     1   4
#[5,]    NA  NA
#[6,]    NA  NA
#[7,]    NA  NA
#[8,]    NA  NA
```

Comment: `str_which` is vectorized and this means that the shorter argument gets recycled. So for `str_which(data$c, c("new1", "var1"))` goes like: `data$c[1]` with `"new1"`, `data$c[2]` with `"var1"`, `data$c[3]` with `"new1"` (see the recycling?), `data$c[4]` with `"var1"` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As nicola has indicated if you provide a vector of strings to `str_locate` it will recycle the arguments. Instead, try to use the OR(`|`) operator. Try something like,

```
str_locate(data$b, "new1|var1")

     start end
[1,]     1   4
[2,]     1   4
[3,]     1   4
[4,]     1   4
[5,]    NA  NA
[6,]    NA  NA
[7,]    NA  NA
[8,]    NA  NA
```

---

I think this is what you are looking for,

```
purrr::map(data, function(x)str_which(x, "new1|var1"))
$a
integer(0)

$b
[1] 1 2 3 4

$c
[1] 1 5
```